# How to stop a vertical stack of observers looping from right angle pistons?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

On Minecraft bedrock
I have a tree farm and on the output is a whole panel of pistons. Once the trunks reach the end I want the pistons to activate and move the trunks to a second row, clearing the way for another first row. The end piston causes an observer loop with a stack of observers. I tried a redstone torch under the end spot instead, with the end trunk causing a circuit that way, but trees don't always grow equally. I need a signal once any part of a 6 high column of trunks reaches the end of my piston wall. Ideally, the observers will see the trunk, power the piston, deactivate for a few seconds then reactivate ready for the next row.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot so we can see what you currently use? Welcome to Arqade!

Comment: I can't take a picture that is less than 2mb so won't let me add it.